# Cannot include libxml2 in my framework, can I include its source code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, libxml2

I am creating a framework for iOS in objective-c with X-Code. This framework uses the library libxml2 that I can not include with the framework itself (simply it is not possible for frameworks). Then the user which want to use my framework needs to include that library, because the compiler sees that the framework uses code that is not available.

Rather than using the library available for iOS, can I compile the source files freely downloadable from the Internet? This way I could include libxml2 into my framework!

Here is the official site of the libxml2 library: http://xmlsoft.org/

Comment: "can I compile the source files" - if you couldn't, there would be no point in writing that library (and in the whole C language itself).

Comment: I agree with Rob Napier that you [should not nest libraries/frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14197817/1271826). Let the developer know what other frameworks are needed and let them add them to the project themselves.

Comment: The problem is that if the developer want to use my framework he must include also frameworks that it does not use...