# Include an iOS Framework into another one

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

The problem is that when I create a framework for iOS, that uses a different framework, I have to also include the second framework in my application.

What I want to try is to compile the second framework into the new one that uses it. so it's all one package. Is this even possible?

If so, how?

Comment: I you created the first one it shouldn't be a problem, but why do you want them to put together? It wouldn't make any difference?

Comment: because the second one is licensed and I can't just give it away along with my own framework

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but strongly recommended against. If two frameworks both include another framework in this manner, you wouldn't be able to use both in the same project as the symbols would conflict. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14197817/72176

If the second framework is licensed in a way that it can't be given away separately with your framework, I'd be very surprised if you were permitted to distribute it as part of your framework either.