# Creating own library that depends on RxSwift still need to import RxSwift?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, rx-swift

I try to create a library called `MyLib` using RxSwift as dependency, which using cocoapod command `pod lib create`. However, the following code doesn't work.

```
import UIKit
import MyLib

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // compile error: Use of unresolved identifier 'Observable'
    Observable.just("")
  }

}
```

It only works after I add `import RxSwift`

I would like to just import `MyLib` only, have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why you can't just use `import RxSwift`? `Observable` isn't your class so with respect to RxSwift developers it is advisable to use this import

Comment: Then the user of my library need to import MyLib and RxSwift, if my library depends on other 4 dependencies, then the user need to import many dependencies in order to use my library

Comment: Have you tried using typealias for `Observable` in your library?
For example: `public typealias Observable = RxSwift.Observable`

Comment: AFAIK most module system does this. Additionally, the user may not really need all those imports anyway. If the dependency is contained in you library and not used directly by the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS framework with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194577/ios-framework-with-dependencies)

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski i think `public typealias` is what I want, do you mind to reply this topic? so I can mark yours as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Observable` isn't your class so with respect to RxSwift developers it is advisable to use this import.

But if you really want then try use typealias for `Observable` in your library?

For example: `public typealias Observable = RxSwift.Observable`